# Existence of a limit from limsup and liminf

Tags: probability, limits, limsup-and-liminf, almost-everywhere

Consider a sequence of random variables $(p_n)$ such that:

(1) $\Pr\bigg(\limsup_{n \to \infty} p_n\leq U\bigg)=1$

(2) $\Pr\bigg(\liminf_{n \to \infty} p_n\geq L\bigg)=1$

where $L,U$ are real numbers. Does these assumptions imply
$$
\Pr\bigg(\lim_{n \to \infty}d\big(p_n, \big[L,U\big]\big)= 0\bigg)=1,
$$
where $d(p_n,  [L,U] ):= \inf \{|p_n - y| : y \in [L,U ] \}$. In other words, I wonder if the limit of the distance exists.

Intuitively, I think it exists. In fact, by (1) and (2), $\inf \{|p_n - y| : y \in [L,U ] \}$ becomes almost surely zero.
Could you help me to show this formally?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): edit your post to include your attempts.

Comment: Thanks @AnneBauval I have added my intuition for why it should hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not much probability here: You show that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} p_n≤U$ and $\liminf_{n\to\infty p_n} ≥ L$ together imply $\lim_{n\to\infty} d(p_n, [L,U])$ for a not-random sequence $(p_n)$. This then implies
$$
  \mathbb P(\lim_{n\to\infty} d(p_n, [L,U])) ≥ \mathbb P\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty} p_n≤U, \liminf_{n\to\infty p_n} p_n ≥ L \right) = 1.
$$

To show the non-probabilistic result, note that $d(p_n,[L,U]) = \max(p_n-U, L-p_n, 0)$. But since $\limsup_{n\to\infty} p_n-U, \limsup_{n\to\infty} L-p_n$ and $\limsup_{n\to\infty} 0$ are all 0, this means that the limsup of the maximum, $d(p_n,[L,U])$ must be smaller equal 0. But because the limit is not negative, this already implies that $\lim_{n\to\infty}d(p_n,[L,U]) = 0$.